# Syntax error by creating a .conf file which is supposed to run a .sh script by starting ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, bash, shell, startup, init

I am trying to simply write a .conf file which will run a .sh script when my linux system starts (ubuntu 16.10)

- The .conf file is located in /etc/init
- When I run my -sh script, it works (./Documents/coding/LinuxProjetPerso/ScriptComputerStart/sendMail.sh)
- When I check the syntax of my .conf file, with "init-checkconf /etc/init/myscriptcomputerstart.conf", I get "ERROR: File /etc/init/myscriptcomputerstart.conf: syntax invalid:"

Here is my really simple .conf file:

```
description     "my job"
start on startup
task
exec /Documents/coding/LinuxProjetPerso/ScriptComputerStart/sendMail.sh
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: the file `/Documents/coding/LinuxProjetPerso/ScriptComputerStart/sendMail.sh` doesn't exist. try adding `/home/yourUserName/Documents/...`

Comment: You are running `./Documents/...`, which I assume is relative to your home directory. That is very different from `/Documents/...` that you reference from the conf file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And sorry, indeed this post should not be in this category. Unfortunately, I did not manage to solve my issue so far. I will keep investigating